# a method that takes Dictionary with different data types

Tags: c#

The following code goes to a class called Formula and generates numbers and labels for the formula.  These come back in 2 separate Dictionarys because the numbers are double data type and the labels are string.

```
Formula formula = new Formula(formula_type, primary_output, fat_values);

Dictionary<string, double> numbers = formula.generateNumbers();
Dictionary<string, string> labels = formula.generateLabels();
```

I am trying to create a method that can be fed either of these Dictionarys but am stuck on what to put in as the data type in the method signature (see ??? in code below).

```
private static void displayData(string text, Dictionary<string, ???> dict)
{
  string words = "The " + text + " Dictionary contains the following:";
  Console.Out.WriteLine(words);
  foreach (var pair in dict)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(pair.Key + "=>" + pair.Value);
  }
  Console.Out.WriteLine("");
}
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?  If the solution is complex, an alternative approach would be preferable because simplicity is important.

Comment: Use object for ???.  The use pair.Value.ToString()

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Tuple<double, string>>` if you want a double & string per key.

Comment: Make your method generic. `private static void displayData<TValue>(string text, Dictionary<string, TValue> dict)`

Comment: @jdweng, that's not the best advice/practice, generics are much more powerful, adaptable to other situations.

Comment: @AlexK that's not what the asker is asking for, "I am trying to create a method that can be fed either of these Dictionarys[sic]"

Comment: Well yes of course, I am illustrating that multiple types be encompassed in a single dictionary under the same key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods)

```
private static void displayData<T>(string text, Dictionary<string, T> dict)
{
  string words = "The " + text + " Dictionary contains the following:";
  Console.Out.WriteLine(words);
  foreach (var pair in dict)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(pair.Key + "=>" + pair.Value.ToString());
  }
  Console.Out.WriteLine("");
}
```

To call:

```
displayData<string>("text",labels);
```

Comment: If you want, when calling the `displayData` method you can drop the `<string>` part since it will be inferred from the variable that's passed in: `displayData("text",labels);`.

Comment: You can also drop the `ToString` on `Value` since you're concatenating it to a `string` which will implicitly call `ToString` for you.

Comment: This works perfectly!  It also seems to work without the .ToString() on the end of .Value.  Is there a reason to include it?